# Element of a given norm in ring of integers of a number field

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find an element of norm $-431$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is the ring of integers of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ a root of $x^4-3$. So far I've shown that the class group Cl$_K$ is trivial hence $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a PID and I have also factored:
$(431)=(431,\alpha-6)(431,\alpha+6)(431,\alpha^2+36)$ into primes where the first two have norm $431$ and the third one has norm $431^2$ but I can't find a generator for either of the first two primes even though I know it exists, but even If I did I would still have to check that its norm is negative and not possitive which makes me thing this is not the right approach.
Is there a possibly different path I could follow?

Answer (score 1):

The norm of $\alpha+6$ is $3\ .\ 431$ so $\frac{\alpha+6}{\alpha}=1+2 \alpha^3$ has norm $-431$.

Comment: Ah yes because $\alpha$ has norm $-3$. Thank you!